# Svg to pdf converter for Qt project

Tags: qt

I have multiple svg files and I wish to convert them in the PDF format. The problem is that I need to work with multiple text fonts and a simple QSvgRenderer is not enough.

For example:
[image]

My problem is that I need to integrate a library in my project that does not use external dependencies (just a library that can be used as a standalone entity).

The only library that can partially suit my needs is [librsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/download/) but I have no experience and I can not find a method to integrate it in a Qt project.

Can someone give me a few tips or can point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

With something basic there is not a single font that made it to the right using QSvgRenderer:

```
  QSvgRenderer renderer;
  renderer.load((QString)"E:/TEXT4.svg");

  QPrinter printer;
  printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
  printer.setOutputFileName("E:/TEXT4.pdf");

  QPainter painter(&printer);
  renderer.render(&painter);
  painter.end();
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to figure out your problem and fail to connect how can fonts effect svg to pdf conversion?

Comment: Multiple fonts are not supported in this kind of conversion. For example in the previous image only two fonts are convertible.

Comment: So are you trying to convert fonts to svg then to pdf or just svg to pdf. Because why should QSvgRenderer even care about fonts? Could you maybe provide us with [mcve]

Comment: I added a minimal example of how QSvgRenderer is not good for fots. I just need Svg to Pdf conversion.

Comment: @student share your .svg file, please

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4315f311cb70f435005eeda5eb5c099920180611123535/df4077

Comment: Sorry for the we transfer link but stack does not support svg upload.

Comment: According to what I see it seems to me that the part that does not reproduce is not supported by Qt since it is an element that belongs to the standard of Corel Draw:

Comment: [cont]  `<g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/> <rect class="fil0 str0" x="10836" y="2596" width="9315" height="9315"/><rect class="fil0 str0" x="10836" y="11911" width="9315" height="9315"/> <rect class="fil0 str0" x="1521" y="2596" width="9315" height="9315"/>
... </g>`

Comment: Any sugestion about how can I make it work or a library that is qt compatible?

Comment: I checked your svg file in chrome, firefox, inkscape, LibreOffice Draw and none of those got me the expected output you showed. All I got was this: https://imgur.com/a/c3Oq6eB . So I wouldn't be pointing fingers at Qt and it's svg rendering backend. But instead validate svg file you provided.

Comment: Inkscape is using librsvg at his core and for the provided example when I try to convert the file it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but had the same problem and found a solution using Qt only.
The problem in your case is you need to install the fonts manually and need a `QApplication`.
E.g.:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // A QApplication instance is necessary if fonts are used in the SVG
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/DejaVuSans.ttf");
    if (id != -1)
    {
        QStringList font_families = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id);
        // This prints: DejaVu Sans
        for (const auto& item : font_families)
        {
            std::cout << item.toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Load your SVG
    QSvgRenderer renderer(QString("myimage.svg"));

    QPdfWriter pdfWriter(QString("mydoc.pdf"));
    pdfWriter.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));
    QPainter painter(&pdfWriter);
    renderer.render(&painter);
}
```

Also tested with multiple different font families and it worked.

Note: As far as I know, you cannot change the font name in Qt, so in the SVG `font-family` must match exactly the added font name. In this example, `font-family:DejaVu Sans`.